# Ubuntu stopped responding just after boot

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse

I have HP Probook 445 g1 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

Now the problem is that when I boot up my PC it boots perfectly but after 4–5 seconds of  entering the password, the mouse & keyboard stopped responding. Every attempt to type or click does not work.

Comment: Please try this: reboot, but do not log in on the GUI. Try to open a text terminal somehow (virtual termina, or by ssh) and see whether that's stable.

Comment: yes that's stable. even when i boot from live usb it works perfect.

Comment: Do you see any errors in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/kern.log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might help

Boot to your installed system, switch to a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and install Unity2D.

```
sudo apt-get install Unity2D
```

Restart GDM

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

and switch back to your login screen (Ctrl+Alt+F7..F9) if it does not do so automatically.

At the bottom of the screen, you will find a list of options; look for Unity2D in one of the dropdown boxes. Select it, and login as normal. (You may have to enter your username before being allowed to select Unity2D as your desktop environment).

Comment: "Unable to locate package Unity2D" error when installing and unable to find service gdm when running the second command.
but at the login screen when logged in with Ubuntu2D the the thing works absolutely fine.
now I want to know what is problem with normal Ubuntu and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Reboot, but do not log in on the GUI.
Try to open a text terminal somehow (virtual termina, or by ssh) and see whether that's stable.

(I asked this as comment originally. It did work to get a stable text terminal as hoped.)

Now, assuming that works - great!

Now, you have a broken system, and an old version "12.04 LTS".
Fixing is easier in a new version, and I see not much reason why the problem should still exist after changing out all the software on the machine.

So, let's just do that, update to Ubuntu 14.4 and see how it works out - any objections?

If that's not possible, you can start with a normal package update anyway... let's see...
Did not help? Hmmm...
One more shot into the blue: We uninstall, and reinstall all the input related parts of X:

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all`
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Hope that helps- otherwise, we'll need to actually search the problem, I think...
Like... *What kind of graphics, which driver do you use?*

---

<sub>For directions to upgrade to the current Ubuntu version, see

[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)</sub>

Comment: Actually the laptop was provided to me by my College and I am not allowed to change any software installed in it. I have to do this with 12.04 installed

Comment: Added alternative - after that, we'll need to start debuging, I guess ;)

Comment: Just to check: do you use a touchpad? Try this if you have one `synclient TouchpadOff=0` - from a text terminal (man need `export DISPLAY=:0.0`)

Comment: same problem after installing updates

Comment: one new happened just now when I again booted up in 2D mode the same problem appears mouse and keyboard did not respond but earlier they were responding.

Comment: @user3774755 Ok. Let's collect some information for a start. Could you `pastebin` the X log files? Like `pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`, maybe `pastebinit /var/log/Xorg.0.log` too? It uploads the file to Canonical, and gives you a link.

Comment: You may try the new command in my edit?

Comment: the driver I use for graphics is propriety driver.

Comment: Driver package version? Card or chip name - `lspci | grep -i vga`?

Comment: soory for the late reply I have AMD radeon HD 8450G

Comment: and running the above makes things more worse the computer got stuck at purple screen when I run the xorg command mentioned above

Comment: Oh... Just to get it right, you say that you were reinstalling X-related packages from a terminal, and while the packages were set up by the installer, your computer was hanging, showing a purple screen, before the apt-get command was finished?

Comment: I think when an installer can crash X, the probability is high it's a X driver problem. It's time to check whether it's a known bug: Can you google for various groups from these words, for a start? :AMD radeon HD 8450G, HP Probook, ubuntu hangs apt-get install update linux X11 xorg crash"